# Change the page shown with yourwebsite.com/#/page

Tags: url

I have seen in various websites (like http://www.dennys.com) that they use `example.com/#/examplepage` or `example.com/#examplepage`. I wanted to do this for my site, but I can't find anything when I search it up.

Comment: We need a lot more information than you have given to help you with this. How are you serving the pages? Servlets? CGI? NodeJS?

Comment: Try window.location.hash = 'somehash'

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:**
To change the page shown you can try

1) set timer to monitor hash change
Example:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(oldHash != hash){
            //load new page through ajax
    }
}, 
50);
```

2) use onpopstate event of window object.
Example:

```
window.onpopstate = function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    //load new page through ajax
}
```